# Snapping to increment: I'd like both Rotate and Scale to work in the same increment as Move, instead of 1/10 the increment

Tags: snapping

Basically I'm trying to make Blender work sort of like MagicaVoxel (I have my reasons), making it so that a cube will snap to a fixed increment for Moving, Rotation and Scale, say 10 cm.

Moving works just fine in this regard, but frustratingly, scale and rotate both operate at 1/10 the increment I've set up. Surely there's a way around this?

I need to snap rotation of all objects to 90 degrees (yes I know how to do that, I'd just like it to SNAP rotate), and I'd like it to scale to the same 10 cm increment.

Anyone know how to do this?